# Attribute type "Virtual" is not supported. Remove attribute "XYZ" from the query, and try again

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm converting SQL to FetchXml for migrating existing reports in Dynamics CRM 2013 to Dynamics CRM 2015 online. There is an optionset and ran into this issue that

**The attribute type "Virtual" is not supported. Remove attribute "s_expensetypename" from the query, and try again.**

The problem is: How to get optionset label and value in link-entity using Fetch Xml CRM 2015 Online.

Here's my Fetch XML:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">  
<entity name="new_timereport">
    <attribute name="new_timereportid" alias="InvoiceID" />
    <attribute name="new_name" alias="Invoice Number" />
    <attribute name="new_projectid" alias="ProjectID" />
    <attribute name="new_projectidname" alias="Project Name" />
    <attribute name="new_customeridname" alias="Customer Name" />
     <filter>
      <condition attribute="new_timereportid" operator="eq" value="@SubreportParam" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="new_expenses" from="new_expenseid" to="new_timereportid" alias="Y" link-type="outer">
      <attribute name="s_expensetype" alias="Expense Type Key" />
      <attribute name="s_expensetypename" alias="Expense Type" />
      <attribute name="ownerid" alias="ConsultantID" />
      <attribute name="owneridname" alias="Consultant" />
      <attribute name="new_date" />
      <attribute name="new_amount" alias="Amount" />
      <attribute name="new_vat" alias="VAT" />
      <attribute name="new_total" alias="Total Amount" />
      <attribute name="new_name" alias="Description" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Many thanks,

Comment: use advanced find to build your query first and after download the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove s_expensetypename field from FetchXml query and leave s_expensetype. In datasource as result you will get 2 fields instead on 1 - s_expensetype will contain label of your optionset and sexpensetypeValue will contain optionsetcode.